# Utilizando template, por que utilizar o modificador const nessa variável (C++)?

Tags: c++, template

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <unsigned int i> 
struct Fibo{
    static const unsigned result = Fibo<i-1>::result + Fibo<i-2>::result;
};

template <>
struct Fibo<0>{
    static const unsigned result = 1;
};

template <>
struct Fibo<1>{
    static const unsigned result = 1;
};

int main () {
    cout << Fibo<5>::result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Se o modificador const é retirado, o compilador declara

> error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Membros de dado estáticos precisam de uma inicialização fora da declaração da classe. Isto é:

```
struct S {
    static int i;
};

int S::i = 42; // definição
```

Isso é uma restrição da linguagem, seguindo a [*regra de uma definição*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (one definition rule, ou ODR).
A restrição existe para impedir que duas ou mais inicializações existam para o membro estático `S::i` (por exemplo, se a classe for incluída em duas unidades de tradução distintas). Observação: a inicialização precisa aparecer apenas em uma unidade de tradução, caso contrário o comportamento é indefinido.

Com o qualificador `const`, a padronização permite inicializar o membro estático com alguma expressão constante (isto é, pode-se inicializar com um literal como `42`, mas não pode inicializar com algum valor que não resulte em uma expressão constante).

Em [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), é possível usar o especificador `inline` para permitir a inicialização do membro de dado no mesmo local de sua declaração:

```
struct S {
    static inline int i = 42;
};
```

Aqui, o `inline` tem o mesmo efeito quando aplicado em funções: sua inicialização pode aparecer em uma ou mais unidades de tradução (contanto que sejam equivalentes, e.g. incluída por uma diretiva `#include`) e apenas uma delas será utilizada de fato.